# Send Notification to all users that followed some author

Tags: php, author, notifications

I'm trying to send notifications for who followed some author when he published new post!

But it always sent to only one user not to all the followers!

So how can i send to all followers ids?

Thanks!

> **UPDATE**

Now it working after change `$user_id` to `$author`

```
$followers = get_user_meta($author, '_pwuf_followers', true);
```

Good luck!

```
function to_followers_only_notify( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {

    global $post;

    if ( 'publish' !== $new_status or 'publish' === $old_status )
        return;

        $user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $followers = get_user_meta($user_id, '_pwuf_followers', true);
        $followers = array_unique($followers);

        $post = get_post($post->ID);
        $author = $post->post_author;
        $author_name = get_the_author_meta( 'display_name', $author );

        $title = '<strong>'.$author_name.'</strong> ' . __('Published new post', 'dw-notifications'). ' <strong>'.$post->post_title.'</strong>';
        $link =  get_permalink($post->ID);
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'post');
        $notif = array('title'=>$title, 'link' => $link, 'image' => $image);

        if ( !empty( $followers ) && is_array( $followers ) ) {

            $follower_ids = array();
            foreach( $followers as $follower ) {
                if ( is_numeric( $follower ) ) {

                    if(!$post->post_author || $post->post_author == $follower) continue;


                    $follower_ids[] = $follower;

                }
            }
            dwnotif_add_notification($follower_ids, $notif);
        }

}
add_action( 'transition_post_status', 'to_followers_only_notify', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: How are followers implemented? WordPress doesn't have followers out of the box

Comment: hmmm googling suggests this is a 3rd party plugin by Pippins Plugins, https://pippinsplugins.com/series/creating-a-user-follow-system-plugin/ but also that you yourself asked this very question, and included more information than here on stackoverflow here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51266194/wordpress-send-email-to-users-when-they-get-new-followers, and got a working answer

Comment: Thnx tom, yeah but it was for notify users when someone followed the others! Now i need to notify the users that followed an author when he published new post. So how can i get first the users followers ids of the post author ID to send for them the notification, did you get it now :)

Comment: Question updated, I just missed to change the `$user_id` to `$author`

Comment: Keep in mind that 3rd party plugins aren't on topic on this stack, but yes, the author ID is the user ID